# Why does it still show deleted file when I am git pushing after I deleting my local files

Tags: git

1. I have a git repo. Yesterday I accidentally created many large files in the folder (say 5 GB).
2. When I `git push origin master` today, it shows files too large to be upload to remote.
3. I deleted these files by just manually moving them to trash.
4. Then the issue comes:
   I did `git add` (and I tried `git add -A`) and then `git commit -m "blabla"` and `git push origin master`.

It still has warning that some files are too large, but they are already deleted.

How should I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

you can untrack the files by running `git rm --cached fileName` To check that the file is removed or untracked run `git ls-files` Then you have to commit your changes by running `git commit -m "UntrackFile"` and you push by using `git push`

If you want to make sure that the file is untracked run `git status -s`before pushing

Comment: But I already deleted those file. I do not even remember the file names. What I want to do is to totally delete those intermediate commits. Is this possible?

Comment: run `git ls-files` to see what files are still tracked